# How to add multithreading support to WebApp2?

Tags: python, multithreading, webapp2

I'm using Python 2.7 with WebApp2 and I'm new to both of them. I'm running WebApp2 outside App Engine and am following [official tutorial](https://webapp-improved.appspot.com/tutorials/quickstart.nogae.html#tutorials-quickstart-nogae).

Provided HelloWord uses Paste web server and works fine, but if I modify it this way (added some sleeping):

```
import webapp2

class HelloWebapp2(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        import time
        time.sleep(6)
        self.response.write('Hello, webapp2!')

app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
    ('/', HelloWebapp2),
], debug=True)

def main():
    from paste import httpserver
    httpserver.serve(app, host='127.0.0.1', port='8080', use_threadpool=True)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

and open few tabs simultaneously than it is obvious that this HelloWord runs in one thread. I added use_threadpool=True just for verbosity, as far as I understand (from reading Paste docs) it should use multithreading anyway even without threadpool.

I tried googling, but unfortunately all I get is that "webapp2 is thread-safe when the module webapp2_extras.local is available". That doesn't help me at all.

Please, show me how to modify this HelloWord to answer requests asynchronously!

P.S. Side question: if I were using Go, could I just run every handler in goroutine to achieve basic concurrency? Or should they (goroutines) only be used for small functions? As I'm not married to Python yet, I am evaluating any alternative.

Edit: I found that it was Google Chrome's problem, not Python's. In other browsers everything works as expected, so the example already is running in multiple threads. I have no idea how to close question here, though.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the following flag to your app.yaml file:

> threadsafe: yes

see [this](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/python25/migrate27#appyaml)

Comment: Dead link, any idea what the documentation you intended to point to was about?